# Create Custom Layout in Constraint Layout Android

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

How to make custom layout in constraint layout according to the layout  shown in image 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Icon at left-parent + right-parent

EditText at left-toRight-icon + right-parent

Button INSIDE EditText with right-gravity

Custom background in EditText

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iconImage"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/iconImage"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@id/imageBtn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:hint="I want to..." />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: we used constraint layout so that there will be no hierarchy so could we use the linear layout in it??

Comment: @HarleenDutt I have edited the answer to use only `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: thanku, but your answer is not correct, because if i put the edittext end point to start of right imageview , then how will i show that icon in edittext